# Getting 403 forbidden when using Twitter Fabric to get user_timeline

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I've been trying to implement Fabric to get a list of the 5 latest tweet from a user. It worked great for a few hours and then it stopped working. I would like to do this without having the user log in, and as far as I can tell the API allows guest-logins to read tweets, but maybe this has a greater effect on the Rate Limit?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig), new Crashlytics());
    TwitterCore.getInstance().logInGuest(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result result) {
            AppSession session = (AppSession) result.data;
            getTweets();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // unable to get an AppSession with guest auth
        }
    });
}

    public void getTweets() {

    TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();
    StatusesService statusesService = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();


    statusesService.userTimeline([USERID], null, 5, null, null, null, true, null, false, new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result <List<Tweet>> result) {

            for(Tweet Tweet : result.data) {
                tweetList.add(Tweet.text);
            }
            createListView();
        }
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Log.e("Failure", exception.toString());
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

When I don't get the 403 everything works perfectly and my list gets populated.

Now, it's entirely possible that there is just something wrong my code that gets me rate limit blacklisted? Otherwise; do I need have the user log in just to show them 5 tweets? Or should I implement some sort of serverside-cache?

Thankful for any tips/help.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue.  It was working fine most of the day, then just a little bit ago it stopped working returning "403".  There's been no changes in my code and I can't imagine I've hit any sort of rate limit (if so, then there's no way Fabric will be useful)

Comment: Strange. I've contacted Twitter (Fabric team I guess) to see if I have in facet hit some sort of limit. I'm pretty new to Android, so I could've made some noob error. But if you are having the same problem there might be something off.

Comment: Hmm..  seems as though clearing app cache and data fixed it.  I'm not sure what's going on.  I added a TwitterCore.getInstance().logoff() in my code to see if that has anything to do with it.  Perhaps it's using a cached authorization token or something and maybe calling logoff() will clear it.  That's my best guess at the moment though.  Might have just been coincidence it happened to us at roughly the same time.

Comment: That did not work for me. What did work though was authenticating with my twitter account, i.e logging in. After that, no problems. Although that might not be the user experience you're going for.

Comment: Yeah, didn't work for me either.  I woke up this morning and it wasn't pulling tweets any more (clearing app data did make it work though, but that's not a reasonable solution).  Unfortunately, logging in with a Twitter account isn't going to work for my purpose (I just want to have a company's tweets embedded in the app and a user shouldn't have to authenticate for that).  I'll be playing around with it more today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I might have it figured out.  Looks like you have to save the session from the success method in the logInGuest callback and then pass that to getApiClient.  Here's some code that's working for me so far:

```
private TweetViewFetchAdapter adapter;
...
adapter = new TweetViewFetchAdapter<CompactTweetView>(getActivity());
...
TwitterCore.getInstance().logInGuest( new Callback<AppSession>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<AppSession> appSessionResult) {
        AppSession session = appSessionResult.data;
        TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient =  TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient(session);
        twitterApiClient.getStatusesService().userTimeline(null, "RadioOkinawa864", 10, null, null, false, false, false, true, new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> listResult) {
                adapter.setTweets(listResult.data);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Could not retrieve tweets", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Could not get guest Twitter session", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Comment: Cool! I'll try it when I get to work. Nice find. :-)

Comment: Works great! I paired it with `TwitterSession currentSession = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
        if (currentSession == null) {`and then the code for logging in.

Comment: Glad it worked for you!  What a coincidence that we ran in to this same issue at roughly the same time.

Comment: And a few timezones away. Isn't the internet fantastic? ;)

Answer (score 3):

When using `logInGuest`, be aware that guest AppSessions will expire after some time. Your application must handle expiration TwitterExceptions and request another guest AppSession. For example,

```
TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient =  TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient(guestAppSession);
twitterApiClient.getSearchService().tweets("#fabric", null, null, null, null, 50, null, null, null, true, new Callback<Search>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<Search> result) {
        // use result tweets
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
        final TwitterApiException apiException = (TwitterApiException) exception;
        final int errorCode = apiException.getErrorCode();
        if (errorCode == TwitterApiConstants.Errors.APP_AUTH_ERROR_CODE || errorCode == TwitterApiConstants.Errors.GUEST_AUTH_ERROR_CODE) {
            // request new guest AppSession (i.e. logInGuest)
            // optionally retry
        }
    }
});
```

Note that AppSessions may only be used to make API requests that do not require a user context. For example, you *cannot* Tweet with an `AppSession`. You *can* get a user's timeline of public Tweets. See [TwitterKit Android REST API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/api).

Finally, if you are using the `TweetUtils.loadTweet` or `TweetUtils.loadTweets` helpers from the TweetUi kit of the Twitter kit group, setting up guest auth and handling expiration is performed automatically, you need not call logInGuest yourself.

Comment: Well if you were to use `TweetUtils.loadTweets` you'd have to specify the IDs of the tweets in an array. If I wanted to get the 5 latest tweets from a user I'd have to first get the IDs of those tweets in an array, and then use the TweetUtils. Or am I not getting it right?

Comment: Yes, you are right that TweetUtils expects Tweet ids. To get the latest 5 tweets from a user, you should use guest authentication and the StatusesService userTimeline as you're doing, not TweetUtils.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the api returned 403 forbidden with the following message `Your app may not allow guest auth. Please talk to us regarding upgrading your consumer key.`

Be sure your are not in the same status.